# Simple Injector with Web API 2. PreApplicationStartMethod doesn't run

Tags: .net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-identity, simple-injector, onion-architecture

I am following Onion Architecture for my Web API and AngularJS Project. In the Infrastructure.DependencyResolution part, I am using Simple Injector. Here is my code:

```
[assembly: PreApplicationStartMethod(typeof(IocConfig), "RegisterDependencies")]
namespace Infrastructure.DependencyResolution
{
    public class IocConfig
    {
         private static Container _container;

         public static void RegisterDependencies()
         {
              _container = new Container();

              _container.Verify();

              _container.RegisterWebApiRequest<IEntitiesContext>(() =>
              {
                   return new MyContext();
              });

              _container.RegisterWebApiRequest<IUserRepository, UserRepository>();
              _container.RegisterWebApiRequest<IAccountService, AccountService>();
              _container.RegisterWebApiRequest<IUnitOfWork, UnitOfWork>();

         }
    }
}
```

Now If I try to put url to go to my account controller, I am getting this error:

> An error occurred when trying to create a controller of type
>   'AccountController'. Make sure that the controller has a parameterless
>   public constructor.

I searched and found out that Simple Injector has some different code for Web Api as suggested by their [site](http://simpleinjector.readthedocs.org/en/latest/webapiintegration.html) Like:

```
// This is an extension method from the integration package.
container.RegisterWebApiControllers(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
```

I copied that as well but it did not accept GlobalConfiguration.Configuration, I guess because I am using it in a library project.

When I set a break point in the `RegisterDependencies` method, Visual Studio doesn't stop at the break point.

Can someone show me the way where to go?

Comment: *it did not accept GlobalConfiguration.Configuration* What did it accept?

Comment: It means it gave compile time error.

Comment: It just did not recognize library.

Comment: I don't see any relationship between your problem and the Onion archtecture. You might want to rename your question.

Answer (score 5):

You are missing is the registration of the `SimpleInjectorWebApiDependencyResolver` as described in the [Web API integration guide](https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.org/en/latest/webapiintegration.html):

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver =
    new SimpleInjectorWebApiDependencyResolver(container);
```

Without overriding Web API's default `IDependencyResolver`, Web API will simply try to instantiate controller instances itself, and this requires controller types to have a default constructor. By replacing this `IDependencyResolver` with the `SimpleInjectorWebApiDependencyResolver` requests for controller instances are forwarded to the Simple Injector container.

You will have the most succes when using [Simple Injector's Web API Quick Start NuGet package](http://SimpleInjector.Integration.WebApi.WebHost.QuickStart). This will bootstrap your application and allows you to get started quickly.

Comment: GlobalConfiguration is not recognized. I try to include using System.Web.Http but still it is not recognizing. :(

Comment: @UsmanKhalid: `GlobalConfiguration` is defined in the `System.Web.Http.WebHost.dll` assembly. You'll need to include that.

Comment: Added and tried. But still getting the same error, An error occurred when trying to create a controller of type 'AccountController'.....

Comment: @UsmanKhalid: What does `AccountController` derive from? I bet it derives from `Controller` (which is MVC) instead of `ApiController` (which is Web API). Please [read this](https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.org/en/latest/mvcintegration.html) to see how to integrate Simple Injector with MVC.

Comment: public class AccountController : ApiController

Comment: @UsmanKhalid: In that case the `Configuration.DependencyResolver` might get overridden somewhere else in the application after you set it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79194/discussion-between-steven-and-usman-khalid).